# Opening "Open Link in New Tab" dialog automatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a table where the rows are clickable (In React).

My goal: open that dialog that you get when you right click a link, and it shows "Open Link in New Tab", etc. I would like to do this without using `<a/>` tag, because I can neither wrap the `<tr/>` tags with the link tag because of how html tables work, and I also cannot put it in the `<td/>` tag because I need to support a multitude of cell components which I did not define, and are being added regularly by the a dev team (I cant expect them to add links everywhere).

That being said, I've looked for this online and the best I can find is people saying to use an onClick with `window.open`, but I dont think that will open the dialog. Am I missing some configuration for that function or is there a better way to do this? Thank you

Comment: IT's not a dialog, it's a popup menu, but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referencing is called the context menu. You *could* create a custom context menu to accomplish this. However, this is not recommended. The 'open link in new tab' button in the context menu is the browsers way of saying "I recognize the element you clicked on is an attributed link. I know this goes somewhere. This will only work on  tags.

I would recommend finding a way to work with the table data you're given to convert the cell in to a valid link.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm gonna try to find a way to insert a the link into the cell as the table is being built